# How do I fill a circle in numpy or in lists of lists

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array:

```
 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

How do I fill the spaces within the circle with ones?

At the moment the data structure is a 10x10 numpy array, however I can keep the data as 10 lists.

For example list 2 would be:

```
 list_2 = [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
```

Then once the fucntion is applied would become:

```
 list_2 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Please post the part of your code which causes a difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `np.cumsum` over one of the axes (i.e. `0` or `1` as parameter):

```
crcl[crcl.cumsum(0)==1] = 1

array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

*Step-by-step explanation:*

This is the numpy array you start with:

```
crcl
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

The cumulative sum separates the inner form the outer space, as it changes only at the borders:

```
crcl.cumsum(0)
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

So you use it as a mask to address only those indices, where the cumsum equals to `1`.

```
mask = crcl.cumsum(0)==1
```

And set the values of l itself at these positions to `1`:

```
crcl[mask] = 1

crcl
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def fil_list(l):
     begin = l.index(max(l))
     end = l[begin+1:].index(max(l))+begin
     for i in range(begin+1,end+1):
            l[i] = 1
     return l
```

this should work if there is both 1 in the list. However, this is not the fastest way to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

first convert ot list of string, and do following commands:

```
y = [ 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0,
      0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0,
      0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1,
      1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0,
      1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0,
      1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0,
      1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0,
      1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0,
      0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1,
      0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]

yStr = list(map(str,y))
yStr0 = yStr[0]
y0 = list(map(int,yStr0))
```

result of y0:

```
y0 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```